# Meteor random color picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

I wrote this function which should display a random color from this array but it always displays the first one. Is there something wrong with my code? I have tried Googling this and checked the meteor documentation but found nothing useful.

```
randomInitials: function () {
   var chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
   var nLetter = chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*chars.length));
   var sLetter = chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*chars.length));
   var colors = ["#e57373","#f06292","#ba68c8","#9575cd","#7986cb","#64b5f6","#4fc3f7","#4dd0e1","#4db6ac","#81c784","#aed581","#dce775","#fff176","#ffd54f","#ffb74d","#ff8a65","#a1887f","#e0e0e0","#90a4ae"];

   return colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
   return nLetter + sLetter;
},
```

```html
<div class="other-profile">
    <span>{{memberData.profile.initials}}</span>
</div>
```

Right now it looks like this:
[image: Now]

I want this:

[image: This]

Comment: Two return statements is an issue in itself, `return nLetter + sLetter;` will never be hit. Also the random colour picker seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/a3Lq7xtv/. What makes you think there's an issue?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan what do you suggest then?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the problem is the background of every user circle is displayed in the same color instead of a random color... I'll ad an image so you will see what I mean

Comment: where's your helper `randomInitials` called in the template?

Comment: @Monasha its caled with the helper at the start of the html dovument... i didnt want to pos the the entire code because its not practical and it would take up a lot of space...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan posted images

Comment: The `randomInitials` should be called for each of the Members

Comment: `<div class="other-profile" style="background-color: {{randomInitials}}">
    <span>{{memberData.profile.initials}}</span>
</div>`

Comment: @Monasha when i call randomInitials for each of the members the initials inside circle disapear...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128141/discussion-between-monasha-and-weinde).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are returning only colors, your helper needs to look like

```
randomInitials: function () {
    var colors = ["#e57373","#f06292","#ba68c8","#9575cd","#7986cb","#64b5f6","#4fc3f7","#4dd0e1","#4db6ac","#81c784","#aed581","#dce775","#fff176","#ffd54f","#ffb74d","#ff8a65","#a1887f","#e0e0e0","#90a4ae"];
    return colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
},
```

And in your template:

```
<div class="other-profile" style="background-color: {{randomInitials}}">
    <span>{{memberData.profile.initials}}</span>
</div>
```